# Pig - how to iterate on a bag of maps

Tags: hadoop, bigdata, apache-pig

Let me explain the problem. I have this line of code:

```
u = FOREACH persons GENERATE FLATTEN($0#'experiences') as j;
dump u;
```

which produces this output:

```
([id#1,date_begin#12 2012,description#blabla,date_end#04 2013],[id#2,date_begin#02 2011,description#blabla2,date_end#04 2013])
([id#1,date_begin#12 2011,description#blabla3,date_end#04 2012],[id#2,date_begin#02 2010,description#blabla4,date_end#04 2011])
```

Then, when I do this:

```
p = foreach u generate j#'id', j#'description';
dump p;
```

I have this output:

```
(1,blabla)
(1,blabla3)
```

But that's not what I wanted. I would like to have an output like this:

```
(1,blabla)
(2,blabla2)
(1,blabla3)
(2,blabla4)
```

How could I have this ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: In the first block you do `dump j;`, do you mean `dump u;`?  Also, could you provide the output of `DESCRIBE u;`?

Comment: Yes, it was dump u thanks. DESCRIBE u produces this output:         u: {j: bytearray}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming that the $0 you are `FLATTEN`ing in `u` is a tuple.

The overall problem is that `j` is only referencing the first map in the tuple. In order to get the output you want, you'll have to convert each tuple into a bag, then `FLATTEN` it.

If you know that each tuple will have up to two maps, you can do:

```
-- My B is your u
B = FOREACH A GENERATE (tuple(map[],map[]))$0#'experiences' AS T ;
B2 = FOREACH B GENERATE FLATTEN(TOBAG(T.$0, T.$1)) AS j ;

C = foreach B2 generate j#'id', j#'description' ;
```

If you don't know how many fields will be in the tuple, then this is will be **much** harder.

---

**NOTE:** This works for pig 0.10.

For tuples with an undefined number of maps, the best answer I can think of is using a UDF to parse the bytearray:

**myudf.py**

```
@outputSchema('vals: {(val:map[])}')
def foo(the_input):
    # This converts the indeterminate number of maps into a bag.
    foo = [chr(i) for i in the_input]
    foo = ''.join(foo).strip('()')
    out = []
    for f in foo.split('],['):
        f = f.strip('[]')
        out.append(dict((k, v) for k, v in [ i.split('#') for i in f.split(',')]))
    return out
```

**myscript.pig**

```
register 'myudf.py' using jython as myudf ;
B = FOREACH A GENERATE FLATTEN($0#'experiences') ;

T1 = FOREACH B GENERATE FLATTEN(myudf.foo($0)) AS M ;
T2 = FOREACH T1 GENERATE M#'id', M#'description' ;
```

However, this relies on the fact that `#`, `,`, or `],[` will not appear in any of the keys or values in the map.

---

**NOTE:** This works for pig 0.11.

So it seems that how pig handles the input to the python UDFs changed in this case.  Instead of a bytearray being the input to `foo`, the bytearray is automatically converted to the appropriate type.  In that case it makes everything much easier:

**myudf.py**

```
@outputSchema('vals: {(val:map[])}')
def foo(the_input):
    # This converts the indeterminate number of maps into a bag.
    out = []
    for map in the_input:
        out.append(map)
    return out
```

**myscript.pig**

```
register 'myudf.py' using jython as myudf ;

# This time you should pass in the entire tuple.
B = FOREACH A GENERATE $0#'experiences' ;

T1 = FOREACH B GENERATE FLATTEN(myudf.foo($0)) AS M ;
T2 = FOREACH T1 GENERATE M#'id', M#'description' ;
```

Comment: unfortunately, i can't know how many fields will be on the tuple :(

Comment: @shanks_roux I've updated my answer to include a way for unknown number of fields.  I'm not happy with it, but it will work.

Comment: thanks for your help ! But why aren't you satisfied of your solution ?

Comment: I'm not satisfied because I couldn't find the pure pig way. There should be __some__ way to do this in pure pig, and it will be faster and won't have the arbitrary rules about what can't appear in the map.

Comment: Yes you're right. I didn't precise that I load the data by using MongoLoader (data are in a mongoDB database), I thik the solution could be in a different use of mongoloader. But your solution seems good though and I thank you for that.

Comment: I tested the solution and there is a bug: "chr(): 1st arg can't be coerced to int". Did you have the same ?

Comment: It works for me, but there are other ways to do this. The byte array foo just needs to be converted to a string.  I'm playing around with some alternative methods right now.

Comment: Does `foo = the_input.tostring()`, instead of `foo = [chr(i) for i in the_input]`, work for you?

Comment: No it doesn't work: "dict object has no attribute tostring()"

Comment: @shanks_roux let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35378/discussion-between-mr2ert-and-shanks-roux)